# Microsoft graph delta and user licenses

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I had been using the Azure Graph APIs and the delta query would return users if their O365 licenses were modified. The assignedLicenses and assignedPlans properties would also be returned.

I've now switched to the Microsoft Graph and neither of these seems to apply.

If I make changes to standard user properties such as their name the delta query will return the user. However, if I make changes to their licenses the delta query doesn't return any users.

If I make changes to their name and licenses the delta query returns the user but the assignedLicenses and assignedPlans are both empty.

I am using the Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

Does anyone know if I am missing something or if this is just not supported in Microsoft Graph or maybe it is just not supported in the .NET library I'm using.

Thanks,
-Paul Judson

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this issue I figured out why it wasn't working. It turns out I wasn't passing $select in my delta request. 

Once I specified the assignedLicenses and assignedPlans in $select everything was returned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment you need to include this as a $select to include those optional properties.